# How do you set the size of a Material Banner?

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design, flutter-layout

I have a column with children and wanted to use a Material banner in order to show information to the user that they might need. I wanted it to be persistent so a snack bar wasn't the way to go, and I wanted it to be non-intrusive so I also didn't want to use a pop-up.

The material banner seems to be what I need but it's too big!

I tried wrapping it in a container and setting the height and width of the container but that just ended up telling me that the bottom was overflowed by X number of pixels.

It appears that the default size for these have a height of 120. When I need it to have buttons for action on it 120 would be perfect but when there is nothing for the user to address I just want the icon, and text telling them they are up to date.

It's possible I'm approaching this the wrong way. Would it be better to leave a container there with the default message and only display the banner if there is a notification available? Can you even do that?

I've looked through the info on flutter's website as well as material.io but I haven't been able to find anything conclusive.

Anyways here's my code that works (without the container wrapping it).

```
MaterialBanner(
 content: Text("You're Up To Date"),
 leading: Icon(
     Icons.check_box_outlined,
     color: Colors.green[400],
     size: 40,
   ),
  actions: [
     FlatButton(
        child: const Text(''),
        onPressed: () {},
       ),
     FlatButton(
        child: const Text(''),
        onPressed: () {},
       ),
    ],
)
```

Also if anyone knows how to set a dropshadow on one of these things that would be cool to learn as well.

Comment: Looks like a lot of padding defined by MaterialBannerTheme and other defaults in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/9b2d32b605/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/banner.dart#L32.  So it's not the size making it large, it's the blank space.  You can probably override some of that to make it smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to this so I won't mark this as answered but I'll provide details on what I did in case someone runs into a similar issue and wants to take the same path I did.

So I was originally using this MaterialBanner to try and give an overview on if the user had notifications they needed to attend to. The MaterialBanner seemed great because it had clickable actions on it. Instead I ended up using a container / card sort of combo to get it done.

My code is here:

```
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('alerts')
        .where('access',
            arrayContains: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .where('read', isEqualTo: false)
        //.orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.docs.length <= 0) {
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                spreadRadius: 5,
                blurRadius: 7,
                offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
              ),
            ],
          ),
          height: 60.0,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              SizedBox(width: 10.0),
              Icon(
                Icons.check_box,
                color: Colors.green,
                size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .1,
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 5.0),
              Expanded(
                child: AutoSizeText(
                  "No Current Messages or Alerts",
                  maxLines: 1,
                  maxFontSize: 20,
                  style:
                      TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              //if (snapshot.hasData) SizedBox(width: 45),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
      Alert alert = Alert.fromFirestore(snapshot.data!.docs.first);
      return Card(
        //height: 60.0,
        child: InkWell(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                Icon(
                  Icons.warning,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .1,
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 15.0),
                Expanded(
                  child: AutoSizeText(
                    "New Alert for Your Patient",
                    maxLines: 1,
                    maxFontSize: 20,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                //if (snapshot.hasData) SizedBox(width: 45),
                if (snapshot.hasData) Icon(Icons.arrow_right, size: 50)
              ],
            ),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => Alert_Info(
                    alert: alert,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
        elevation: 12,
      );
    });
```

Lot of code here so let me walk you through it.

I've got a stream builder setting up a query so I can see if there will be any notifications for the user thats logged in.

If the query comes back with no data it just displays a container saying 'You're up to date"

But if the query comes back with data then it will display a card that has an InkWell inside of it. The card does the job for containing the info I need to display and the InkWell gets the job of letting it be clickable done!

So instead of trying to use a Material Banner (which looking back kinda looks ugly) I ended up creating a solution.

So if you're trying to use a Material Banner for the same use case as me and want it to be a permanent fixture of the UI, then try something like this instead. But Material Banners could still be good for incoming notifications that need attention right away and can be dismissed.